# How to present a ViewController as a popover from a UIMenuItem action

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uimenucontroller

I want to display a ViewController that is filled with a tableView as a popover when a UIMenuItem is tapped. Is this possible? I have done the following in the function that is called when the respecting menu item is tapped:

```
func pickColor(sender: UIMenuItem) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ColorPopOver", sender: view)
}
```

Then I have implemented the methods that handle the segue and presentation of the popover:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ColorPopOver" {
        let destinationController = segue.destination
        if let popOver = destinationController.popoverPresentationController {
            popOver.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

When the pickColor method is called the app crashes, can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Or is it just impossible? Thanks.

Comment: You want to present a UITabeViewController as Alert ?

Comment: No, I want to display something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpRgI.png but I need it to show it from a UIMenuItem action in a menu controller, not a bar button item.

Comment: I don't think that's possible because as soon as a menu button is pressed, the menu disappears, so you can't possibly anchor a popover on a menu item

Comment: @Sweeper that makes a lot of sense, is there a way to prevent the menu from disappearing? This sounds silly, but I really need to present the popover from the menu item since it is a color picker for a selected text.

Comment: @MarilynGarcía Then you should get the rect of the text and use that as an anchor for the popover!